# terminate called after throwing an instance of std::bad_alloc

Tags: c++

I am facing the current error since last few days and fighting with it to resolve the problem but all in vain. I am using Pythia8 and fastjet event generator together and running my simple code. Code compiled nicely but causes run time error as shown below. It runs fine with low events but for large iterations(events) it failed and print the error under discussion:

> PYTHIA Warning in SpaceShower::pT2nextQCD: weight above unity
>       PYTHIA Error in StringFragmentation::fragment: stuck in joining
>       PYTHIA Error in Pythia::next: hadronLevel failed; try again
>       PYTHIA Error in SpaceShower::pT2nearQCDthreshold: stuck in loop
>       PYTHIA Error in StringFragmentation::fragmentToJunction: caught in junction flavour loop
>       PYTHIA Warning in StringFragmentation::fragmentToJunction: bad convergence junction rest frame
>       PYTHIA Warning in MultipleInteractions::pTnext: weight above unity
>       terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
>       what(): std::bad_alloc

```
here is code:
[
double Rparam = 0.4;
fastjet::Strategy strategy = fastjet::Best;
fastjet::RecombinationScheme recombScheme = fastjet::Et_scheme;
fastjet::JetDefinition *jetDef = NULL;
jetDef = new fastjet::JetDefinition(fastjet::antikt_algorithm, Rparam,
recombScheme, strategy);
// Fastjet input
std::vector <fastjet::PseudoJet> fjInputs;



//================== event selection efficiency variables ==========

int nev=0;
int passedJetCut=0;
int passedBJetCut=0;
int passedLeptonCut=0;
int passedMtaunuCut=0;
int passedMtaunubCut=0;
int passedWCut=0;
int passedTopCut=0;
int passedMetCut=0;

int njets=2;
int nbjets=1;
int ntaus=1;
double MW=80.38;

// Begin event loop. Generate event. Skip if error. List first one.
for (int iEvent = 0; iEvent < HowManyEvents; ++iEvent) {

nev++;
if(iEvent%1000==0)cout<<"Event number "<<iEvent<<endl;
// cout<<"Event number "<<iEvent<<endl;
//==================== PYTHIA ==================
if(!pythia.next())continue;

// if (iEvent<3)pythia.process.list();
if (iEvent<2)pythia.event.list();
//if (iEvent<2)event.list();
//==================== TAUOLA ==================

// Convert event record to HepMC
HepMC::GenEvent * HepMCEvt = new HepMC::GenEvent();

//Conversion needed if HepMC uses different momentum units
//than Pythia. However, requires HepMC 2.04 or higher.
HepMCEvt->use_units(HepMC::Units::GEV,HepMC::Units::MM);

ToHepMC.fill_next_event(pythia, HepMCEvt);

// if (FirstEvent)event.list();
//Beware this does not reflect tauola effect
//tauola C++ interface only affects HepMC::GenEvent which is made
// from pythia.event

//run TAUOLA on the event
TauolaHepMCEvent * t_event = new TauolaHepMCEvent(HepMCEvt);

//Since we let Pythia decay taus, we have to undecay them first.
t_event->undecayTaus();
t_event->decayTaus();

// Reset Fastjet input for each event
fjInputs.resize(0);

// Keep track of missing ET

//*******************
class IsbFromTop {
public:
bool operator()( const HepMC::GenParticle* p ) {
if ( abs(p->pdg_id()) == 5 ) return 1;
return 0;
}
};
vector<bjet> bjets;
bjets.clear();

//======================= loop over particles ========================
for(HepMC::GenEvent::particle_const_iterator p = HepMCEvt->particles_begin();
p!= HepMCEvt->particles_end(); ++p ){

int pid=(*p)->pdg_id();
double pt=(*p)->momentum().perp();
double px=(*p)->momentum().px();
double py=(*p)->momentum().py();
double pz=(*p)->momentum().pz();
double e=(*p)->momentum().e();
double eta=(*p)->momentum().eta();
double phi=(*p)->momentum().phi();

if(abs(pid)==15){
if ( (*p)->production_vertex() ) {
for ( HepMC::GenVertex::particle_iterator mother =
(*p)->production_vertex()->particles_begin(HepMC::parents);
mother!=(*p)->production_vertex()->particles_end(HepMC::parents);
++mother )
{
if(abs((*mother)->pdg_id())==24){
W2Tau=true;
}
}
}
}

// Final state only
if ((*p)->status()!=1)continue;
if(abs(pid)==11 || abs(pid)==13){
if(!FoundLepton){
hleptonet->Fill(pt);
hleptoneta->Fill(eta);
hleptonphi->Fill(phi);
pxlepton=px;
pylepton=py;
pzlepton=pz;
elepton=e;
FoundLepton=true;
}
if(pt>20. && pt<80. && fabs(eta)<1.5)
nleptons++;
}
// No neutrinos
if (abs(pid)==12 ||
abs(pid)==14 ||
abs(pid)==16){nnu++;continue;}

// Only |eta| < 5
if(fabs(eta)>5.)continue;


// Missing ET
mex -= px;
mey -= py;


// Store as input to Fastjhttps://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?shva=1#inboxet
fjInputs.push_back(fastjet::PseudoJet (px,py,pz,e));

}//loop over particles in the event

continue.............................

thanks a lot for your help
ijaz
```

Comment: Please provide readable and compilable code. Reduce your problem to the absolute minimum containing the problem. And do yourself a favor and properly _indent_ code.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I don't know anything about Pythia but in c++ new Operator will return either allocated memory pointer or it will throw a bad_alloc exception.

Using try catch we can solve this issue-

Like:

```
while(true)
{
    try
    {
        string s = new string(1024*1024*1024);
        break;
    }
    catch
    {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

It will solve the crashing issue but the CPU utilization will go UP until we got the required memory.(and if CPU reach at 100% usage it will hang the system)

Comment: It was running before for more than hundred thousands of events but now it can only run not more than 2000, as the code is not so complicated, not so many arrays and not so many vectors pointers. i really dont know how to do and not so aware of debugging procedure.

Comment: Here is the output of gdb :                                                                                   0x0295f07e in #13 0x0295b03e in fastjet::ClusterSequence::_initialise_and_run (this=0xbfffe208, 
    jet_def=..., writeout_combinations=@0xbfffe707) at ClusterSequence.cc:77
#14 0x0809bac1 in fastjet::ClusterSequence::ClusterSequence<fastjet::PseudoJet>(std::vector<fastjet::PseudoJet, std::allocator<fastjet::PseudoJet> > const&, fastjet::JetDefinit---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---
ion const&, bool const&) ()
#15 0x080989ab in main ()

Comment: See ljaz Ahmed memory allocation is not in our hand so for the good programming practice new should be written in try catch statement. And I also not good at debugging.

Comment: It is also possible that before days you use old version of some third party lib and in that this issue is taken care of but you upgrade this third party lib and this issue is in updated version. This might be happen.

Comment: Please can you write the "try catch" code a little bit more detail, as to run my code i use the command:    ./Analysishad.exe Analysis.cmnd events_schST_tb60Mhc200_100k.lhe lep21.root 0 10000   , do you want me to put this command in a separate file to run it in gdb. Sorry i dont got you. can you elaborate? thanks

Comment: sorry, i could not get any suitable and reasonable solution of my problem, could someone help in a bit more detail and simple way. I would be grateful to you. thansk

Comment: I would request again if somebody can help me to get rid of this problem, as it took around a month.